# How do I add a WP user role select dropdown to the MEMBERPRESS registration form?

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, user-registration, memberpress

I would like to know if I can insert a WP role select dropdown into the memberpress registration page? (and for them to show up in admin profile, ability to change, the whole deal) Yes, I have read the instructions of how to do this to add this to the default wp registration form, but I would have no clue on how to "mold" that to apply to memberpress registration form? Will it even work with a function, or would I have to edit the memberpress php files? (I have reached out to memberpress, but they refer me to expensive form add ons)

Any help would be of great value to me.

Memberpress does have a "custom field" function, but does not directly integrate with WP core user roles meta, so that is useless. I know how to add functions. This is the function that I found that adds what I need to the default registration form.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290987/add-role-selector-to-custom-registration-page
I don't know what to replace register_form and myplugin_register_form (or is that supposed to be there)? Basically if possible I need the whole code verbatim please!!